# Is it still possible to get Stack Overflow stickers?

Tags: discussion

I recently took a look at moderator candidate [Coldspeed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4909087/coldspeed)'s profile for election purposes, and noticed that in his profile, he has a picture of a t-shirt and some SO stickers.  Now I know that those items were given to him because he has 100k reputation, but I did see a blog post that said you could get stickers by mailing to an address.  Unfortunately, this post was from about 10 years ago, and I've seen some other posts here on meta about stickers that are from a few years ago.  I'm just wondering if it's possible to still get stickers.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you give it a try and let us know?

Comment: I recently received a Stack Overflow sticker (and some other things) for [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316557/395288).

Comment: I've seen people receive sticker relatively recently, I think one of the moderators up for election got you and posted it on their profiles. I'm pretty sure you can still receive them, I think it just varies for what gets you one.